# Do/Until loop asking twice

Tags: powershell, loops, active-directory

This function loops two time after one correct behaviour. I don´t know why.

```
function Kürzel {
   $samaccountname = Read-Host -prompt "Kürzel eingeben"
   Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $SamAccountName}
}

do { 
    if (Kürzel) {
        Write-Host "Kürzel schon vorhanden"
        Start-Sleep -s 1
    }
} until (-not(Kürzel)
```

This is the result. I take a samaccountname 5 times wrong on purpose, but it just write-host 3 times.

```
Kürzel eingeben: pat
Kürzel schon vorhanden
Kürzel eingeben: pat
Kürzel eingeben: pat
Kürzel schon vorhanden
Kürzel eingeben: pat
Kürzel eingeben: pat
Kürzel schon vorhanden
Kürzel eingeben: cet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are invoking the `Kürzel` function inside your `if` and `until` condition. You can simple fix that by introducing a variable and omit the second function call:

```
function Kürzel {
    $samaccountname = Read-Host -prompt "Kürzel eingeben"
    Get-ADUser -F { SamAccountName -eq $SamAccountName }
}

$isUnique = $true


do { 
    if (Kürzel) {
        Write-Host "Kürzel schon vorhanden"
        $isUnique = $false
        Start-Sleep -s 1
    } else {
        $isUnique = $true
    }
} until ($isUnique)
```

Comment: * infitine loop detected * - you need to set `$isUnique = $true` inside the loop body at some point, otherwise it'll run forever if the first provided username is taken.

Answer (score 1):

Save the result of the call to `Kürzel` inside the loop, so you don't have to call it again:

```
do {
    $vorhandenerKonto = Kürzel
    if ($vorhandenerKonto) {
        Write-Host "Kürzel schon vorhanden"
        Start-Sleep -s 1
    }
} until (-not($vorhandenerKonto))
```